# Excel mixed mode error

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use VBA in excel to access an existing app.  When i run my VBA script, i get the mixed mode error message in the application log:

> "Error: Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v2.0.50727' of
>   the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional
>   configuration information."

However, the app that i am calling already has a config file with the following statements:

```
<!-- VS 2010 needs this legacyV2 stuff -->
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
</startup>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Change the config file to include the changes below

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"></supportedRuntime>   
</startup>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip - it is not quite working yet, but has changed the behavior.  I'm trying to work out what is happening now, and may post back.